# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS: "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used." fixed by gdisk yet come back after reboot

Tags: 16.04, gpt, fdisk, gdisk

I have four drives that I put onto a Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Recently during a `fdisk` task I saw the warning message "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.". I searched around and realized that I can fix it by:

1. Run `#gdisk /dev/sda`.
2. Then "p" to make sure the partition table look correct to me.
3. Then "w" to write the partition table back to the disk.
4. Then `fdisk -l /dev/sda` to make sure that the warning message is gone.

I did this for all my drives (which all had this warning for some reason). But after a reboot, all the warnings came back, as you can see in the following.

```
# fdisk -l sd?
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9DC10125-D8EA-41E8-B661-4E75EF48B642

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1         2048   99999743   99997696  47.7G Linux filesystem
sda2     99999744 2053522830 1953523087 931.5G Linux filesystem
sda3   2053523456 3907029134 1853505679 883.8G Linux filesystem
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C0BC6B77-21F3-E947-9360-7E1A57A78F46

Device Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdb1    2048 1953525134 1953523087 931.5G Linux filesystem
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 92B513F9-B8E4-4B81-AF8D-DDEBCA08574E

Device Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdc1    2048 1953525134 1953523087 931.5G Linux filesystem
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6F5855A8-870B-4E6B-893D-5DF83ACD4A2E

Device Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdd1    2048 1953525134 1953523087 931.5G Linux filesystem
#
```

**Question: how to permanently fix the GPT table?**

**EDIT:**

I recall that when I save my `fdisk` changes, I saw something like this. Not sure if this helps the diagnose, but I will post it here anyways:

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Invalid argument
```

**EDIT 2**:

I lied, the `fdisk` error was the following when I write my partition tables:

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy
```

**EDIT 3**:

Followed [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696929/corrupt-backupt-gpt-table) as Rod Smith pointed out in the comment. Before the fix, the last 34 sectors of one of my disk reads:

```
00000000  45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54  00 00 01 00 5c 00 00 00  |EFI PART....\...|
00000010  11 d9 17 78 00 00 00 00  8e 65 70 74 00 00 00 00  |...x.....ept....|
00000020  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  6d 65 70 74 00 00 00 00  04 64 65 a2 24 ad 7d 44  |mept.....de.$.}D|
00000040  89 e5 d0 c1 1d 53 5d 30  6e 65 70 74 00 00 00 00  |.....S]0nept....|
00000050  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  86 d2 54 ab 00 00 00 00  |..........T.....|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200  c3 8c 89 6a d2 1d b2 11  99 a6 08 00 20 73 66 31  |...j........ sf1|
00000210  9e 3d 37 b5 e6 a6 43 c2  b9 ed e3 06 d2 03 07 69  |.=7...C........i|
00000220  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 27 70 74 00 00 00 00  |.........'pt....|
00000230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  7a 00 66 00 73 00 2d 00  |........z.f.s.-.|
00000240  35 00 64 00 64 00 33 00  61 00 38 00 65 00 32 00  |5.d.d.3.a.8.e.2.|
00000250  63 00 65 00 66 00 37 00  36 00 36 00 65 00 39 00  |c.e.f.7.6.6.e.9.|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000600  3b 5a 94 6a d2 1d b2 11  99 a6 08 00 20 73 66 31  |;Z.j........ sf1|
00000610  d0 e7 e2 ee e6 0c 46 9c  b2 54 bf b3 67 01 76 ff  |......F..T..g.v.|
00000620  00 28 70 74 00 00 00 00  ff 67 70 74 00 00 00 00  |.(pt.....gpt....|
00000630  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00004200  45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54  00 00 01 00 5c 00 00 00  |EFI PART....\...|
00004210  26 50 e4 36 00 00 00 00  af 6d 70 74 00 00 00 00  |&P.6.....mpt....|
00004220  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........".......|
00004230  8e 6d 70 74 00 00 00 00  28 b3 9e 20 ff 4f 49 2c  |.mpt....(.. .OI,|
00004240  86 0b 7f 92 fc 16 8d 62  8f 6d 70 74 00 00 00 00  |.......b.mpt....|
00004250  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00004400
```

After I use `gdisk` to fix the backup GPT table, the diff of the hex is:

```
23c23
< 00004210  26 50 e4 36 00 00 00 00  af 6d 70 74 00 00 00 00  |&P.6.....mpt....|
---
> 00004210  a9 5b 82 39 00 00 00 00  af 6d 70 74 00 00 00 00  |.[.9.....mpt....|
27c27
< 00004250  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
---
> 00004250  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  26 50 e4 36 00 00 00 00  |........&P.6....|
```

**Question to Rod (our GPT master here): Does this look like a correct fix to you?**

I then rebooted into a Live USB Ubuntu (not the CLI but the GUI -- not sure how to boot into the CLI which might further simplify the problem) and checked the last 34 sectors of the disk again (as Rod suggested in the aforementioned question). The content reverted into the pre-fix state. So apparently it's not because of the (unrooted) ZFS in my Ubuntu system.

My machine is a Dell Precision T7600, which has a PERC H310 Adapter (hardware RAID controller I suppose). All my four HDDs are connected to this controller. So, at this point, I'm thinking maybe it's caused by this RAID controller. However, after I press CONTROL+R into the RAID configuration BIOS, I don't see any options to disable the RAID functionality. I also went into the BIOS setup and found nothing related. This is where I'm stuck - not sure how to completely turn off the RAID controller (e.g. into just a SATA dock). I'm pretty sure that all my HDDs have been configured as non-RAID all the time.

**Question: Is there any other things I should check while I look for instructions to turn the hardware RAID off?**

P.S. My HDDs are partitioned like this:

```
sda1 = ubuntu
sda2 + sdb + sdc + sdd = raidz1
```

Comment: Why not go into recovery and use `fsck` to confirm its ok.

Comment: I suspect that the drives can't be mounted to have this work. Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and try it again. Make sure to `swapoff` any drives with a swap partition before trying this, or the drive will still be busy.

Comment: Hi @RodSmith, I followed your link and found that fixing and rebooting into Live USB will still damage the backup GPT table. I wanted to update my question to add my latest info but the site is preventing me from doing so (somewhat thought I was spamming). I will update the question later when I can. Before that, any suggestions? I am working w/ a Dell Precision T7600 which has a PERC H310 (hardware?) RAID controller but I couldn't find any configuration to turn it off (into simply a SATA dock). Any suggestions?

Comment: p.s. I am sure that the HDDs have been listed as "non-RAID" in the H310 configuration for the whole time. So I wonder maybe it's not caused by the H310.

Comment: The `fdisk` output you're showing after you hit `w` is *not* an error; it's just telling you that it can't reload the partition table because it's in use. This is normal when you use `fdisk` to adjust partitions on a disk that's in use. I suggest you try using the `dd` command in the duplicate question's answer (adjusting the `skip=` value for your disk) to examine the last few sectors of the disk. With any luck you'll find a clue about what's modifying those sectors.

Comment: @RodSmith Just tried and it still wouldn't let me update the answer. The short version is: I followed your suggestion in the other answer and found that the fix is overridden after I reboot into a Live USB. I'm using a storage ZFS raidz1 volume across all 4 disks, w/ the only non-ZFS partition being sda1 which mounts to / (i.e. sda1 = ubuntu, then raidz1 = sda2, sdb, sdc, sdd). Where can I post more info (which I originally wanted to update into my question) so that you can see them? I have the output from `dd | hexdump`, both before and after applying the fix.

Comment: Finally thought about tethering through my cell phone's LTE and was able to update the question. @RodSmith, here you go. Please see my updated question.

Comment: That's a subtle change. I was hoping to see a string with the name of the software making the change. It could be the RAID controller, but that's unlikely; GPT is common enough that I'd expect such bugs to have been fixed by now, assuming you've got up-to-date firmware. (If your firmware is not the latest, though, updating it might be worth trying.) Have you installed any unusual software, like third-party disk encryption tools, unusual boot loaders, etc.? Occasionally they wreak havoc. Standard Linux tools that come with Ubuntu should be OK.

Comment: @RodSmith The workstation has been there for a few years ago. I'm going to just update the firmware and see what happens.